# Adding a column to pivot table which averages sum of the count of each month per year

Tags: vba, excel, pivot, pivot-table

I am attempting to add another column to my pivot table in which it averages the sum of the count for the months within a year and then highlights the months that have a higher count than the average.

I know that there is a way to average in the pivot table, but not in the way that I am looking, as the average that I am looking for is dependent upon the sum of count.

I have not found anyway to do this in my own, and I am not sure if there is a way to do this, without it being overly complicated.

**PIVOT TABLE**

[image]

**CODE**

```
Private Sub pivot()

    Dim sht             As Worksheet
    Dim pvtCache        As PivotCache
    Dim pvt             As PivotTable
    Dim StartPvt        As String
    Dim rep             As Worksheet
    Dim SrcData         As String
    Dim lstrw           As Double

    Set rep = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Report")

    Dim xWs As Worksheet
    Dim sheetName As String
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Err.Clear
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xWs = Sheets("Pivot")
    If Err <> 0 Then
        'Do Nothing
    Else
        xWs.Delete
    End If
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    Set sht = Sheets.Add(, rep)
    sht.Name = "Pivot"

    SrcData = rep.ListObjects("Date_Count")
    StartPvt = sht.Name & "!" & sht.Range("A3").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

    Set pvtCache = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
        SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=SrcData)

    Set pvt = pvtCache.CreatePivotTable( _
        TableDestination:=StartPvt, TableName:="Date_Count Pivot")

    With sht.PivotTables("Date_Count Pivot").PivotFields("Dates")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With

    sht.PivotTables("Date_Count Pivot").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "Date_Count Pivot").PivotFields("Count"), "Sum of Count", xlSum

    sht.Range("A4").Group Start:=True, End:=True, Periods:=Array(False, False, False, _
        False, True, False, True)

    lstrw = sht.Range("A1", sht.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

End Sub
```

Comment: Is it a similar issue to this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21940443/excel-pivot-table-average-of-calculated-sums/48322850#48322850

Comment: @TomJohnRiddle I am not able to do that because this is a company computer and the highest level of Microsoft that I has is 2007

Comment: I had a similar issue with custom columns, what I did was copy the pivot table after it was built, paste as values, delete the pivot table and build the custom columns alongside what was once the pivot table.  Had to do this for average sales per customer and per salesman once in app.  It's not too bad to do.

Comment: I just re-read your question. It seems that changing sum to avarge would be enough (I understand that you have count column in your data)? http://exceldashboardtemplates.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Pivot-Table-Goal-Data-Summarize-Value-Field-by-Average.png

Comment: @TomJohnRiddle, yes I have been looking for something like that, how do you get to that?

Comment: Like this: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2354-excel-pivot-table-change-multiple-field-settings.html :) it seems that link has already vba solution

Comment: I will post a screenshot as an answer, it begins as a pivot table but gets run every day, using vba I make my own table with the calculations.  I will delete the SS after you view it as its not an answer but if its what you are after I will fill out the code.  Take a look and let me know if that is something you are after.

Comment: Moved this up, deleting the answer so others can help, there is some of the pivot manipulation in the answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47946164/8716187

Comment: Maybe I cannot see something but shouldn't change of `sht.PivotTables("Date_Count Pivot").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "Date_Count Pivot").PivotFields("Count"), "Sum of Count", xlSum` to `sht.PivotTables("Date_Count Pivot").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "Date_Count Pivot").PivotFields("Count"), "Average", xlAverage` do the trick?

Comment: @TomJohnRiddle - No, because I want to keep the sum of counts of each year in regards to each month.  What this is doing is average each week within a month.

Comment: @A Cohen I know how to set up a conditional formatting rule that changes the format for the values that are greater than the average in each year; however, I'm not really familiar with coding conditional format rules through vba. The pivot table would need to be in tabular format with repeating item labels. However, you wouldn't actually be able to see an average value for each year. If you think that would be helpful, I can look into getting a start on the vba and posting it.